# xlsxwriter's set_header not working as expected

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I am using `xlsxwriter 1.1.0` and `Microsoft Excel 2016` I copied the example listed [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_headers_footers.html#ex-headers-footers) (my version pasted below):

```
######################################################################
#
# This program shows several examples of how to set up headers and
# footers with XlsxWriter.
#
# The control characters used in the header/footer strings are:
#
#     Control             Category            Description
#     =======             ========            ===========
#     &L                  Justification       Left
#     &C                                      Center
#     &R                                      Right
#
#     &P                  Information         Page number
#     &N                                      Total number of pages
#     &D                                      Date
#     &T                                      Time
#     &F                                      File name
#     &A                                      Worksheet name
#
#     &fontsize           Font                Font size
#     &"font,style"                           Font name and style
#     &U                                      Single underline
#     &E                                      Double underline
#     &S                                      Strikethrough
#     &X                                      Superscript
#     &Y                                      Subscript
#
#     &[Picture]          Images              Image placeholder
#     &G                                      Same as &[Picture]
#
#     &&                  Miscellaneous       Literal ampersand &
#
# See the main XlsxWriter documentation for more information.
#
# Copyright 2013-2018, John McNamara, jmcnamara@cpan.org
#
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('E:\\headers_footers.xlsx')
preview = 'Select Print Preview to see the header and footer'

######################################################################
#
# A simple example to start
#
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Simple')
header1 = '&CHere is some centered text.'
footer1 = '&LHere is some left aligned text.'

worksheet1.set_header(header1)
worksheet1.set_footer(footer1)

worksheet1.set_column('A:A', 50)
worksheet1.write('A1', preview)


######################################################################
#
# Insert a header image.
#
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Image')
header2 = '&L&G'

# Adjust the page top margin to allow space for the header image.
worksheet2.set_margins(top=1.3)

worksheet2.set_header(header2, {'image_left': 'logo.png'})

worksheet2.set_column('A:A', 50)
worksheet2.write('A1', preview)


######################################################################
#
# This is an example of some of the header/footer variables.
#
worksheet3 = workbook.add_worksheet('Variables')
header3 = '&LPage &P of &N' + '&CFilename: &F' + '&RSheetname: &A'
footer3 = '&LCurrent date: &D' + '&RCurrent time: &T'

worksheet3.set_header(header3)
worksheet3.set_footer(footer3)

worksheet3.set_column('A:A', 50)
worksheet3.write('A1', preview)
worksheet3.write('A21', 'Next sheet')
worksheet3.set_h_pagebreaks([20])

######################################################################
#
# This example shows how to use more than one font
#
worksheet4 = workbook.add_worksheet('Mixed fonts')
header4 = '&C&"Courier New,Bold"Hello &"Arial,Italic"World'
footer4 = '&C&"Symbol"e&"Arial" = mc&X2'

worksheet4.set_header(header4)
worksheet4.set_footer(footer4)

worksheet4.set_column('A:A', 50)
worksheet4.write('A1', preview)

######################################################################
#
# Example of line wrapping
#
worksheet5 = workbook.add_worksheet('Word wrap')
header5 = "&CHeading 1\nHeading 2"

worksheet5.set_header(header5)

worksheet5.set_column('A:A', 50)
worksheet5.write('A1', preview)

######################################################################
#
# Example of inserting a literal ampersand &
#
worksheet6 = workbook.add_worksheet('Ampersand')
header6 = '&CCuriouser && Curiouser - Attorneys at Law'

worksheet6.set_header(header6)

worksheet6.set_column('A:A', 50)
worksheet6.write('A1', preview)

workbook.close()
```

On line 40, I changed the destination of the file and on line 68 I changed the name of the image; I have changed nothing apart from that. When I run the said program I don't see the images as well as the fonts. I have attached a screenshot below:[image]

The program finished correctly without throwing any exception. Most of the other functions like `set_column`, `insert_image` etc. are working. But `set_header` isn't.

I don't know if any more information is required. Please feel free to demand for the same if required.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code to your question, instead of linking to external documentation? The documentation may have changed in a year, while your question will still be here.

Comment: @RolandWeber I have added it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers and Footers in Excel don't show up in the normal view of the worksheet. As the output from the example says "Select Print Preview to see the header and footer".

In Print Preview mode the output looks like this:

[image]

Or in "Page Layout" view it looks like this:

[image]